# How to get RichLink in iMessage

Tags: imessage

What code do I need to add to my website in order to get a rich link when someone sends a link of my website via iMessage and not just the standard icon, title, hyperlink?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you need is the following:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> </title>
    <meta name="og:title" content="Insert Titel for iMessage"/>

    //Will be used if internet is to slow to load image or video
    <link rel="icon" href="link to your icon" type="image/png" />

    <meta name="og:image" content="link to your image"/>

    <meta name="og:video" content="link to your video"/>

</head>
...
</html>
```